# partial page refresh of main view from modal window

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view in my MVC4 project, called Products, which displays a list of products.

I have an "Add Product" button, which pops up a modal window, rendering a View with a few fields, and a submit button to add the product.

How do I get the product list on my main view to be updated with the newly added product without a full page refresh?

Comment: Is your "modal window" a true browser window, or a modal *dialog* on a single browser window?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using telerik's window component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried to do exactly that, but you could try the following:

- Have your product list be a partial view
- Have the submit button on the modal dialog do an Ajax form submission (there's lots of examples and posts explaining how to do this, if you're not familiar with it)
- Close the modal dialog
- Re-load the partial view

Because this is a lot of code and views, I can't provide examples of all of it, but if you have specific questions I can try to provide some.